# Is google cloud load balancer hipaa compliance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hipaa

I read the hipaa doc from google, i'm no sure is the google cloud load balancer hipaa complince. [google cloud hipaa](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/hipaa/)

google says all the networks and regions are hipaa complince, i think this includes this products:

- VPC
- cloud DNS
- cloud interconnect
- cloud cdn
- cloud load balancer

is this correct or i'm wrong?

I think it is because kubernetes engine uses cloud load balancer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the documentation that you [provided](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance/hipaa/#covered-products) and in [here](https://cloud.google.com/security/compliance) network is covered by HIPAA.

"The Google Cloud BAA covers GCP’s entire infrastructure (all regions, all zones, all network paths, all points of presence)"

But lets not forget that you need to do your bit by securing the environment and applications that run on top of GCP, hence why it's called a shared security model.